# Is it possible to route to 2 different files in the same folder when routing based off the type of request?

Tags: php, api, routes

While the question sounds a bit scuffed, hear me out: I have 2 files in the same directory. I've been told that it's neater to route based off the type of requests you get (GET, POST, PUT, etc.)

I'm using this bit of code to reroute any GET request I get to the appropriate map, while the url stays 'api/customers'

```
try {

route('/api/customers', [
    'GET' => 'customer/read',
    'PUT' => 'customer/update',
    'POST' => 'customer/create',
    'DELETE' => 'customer/delete',
]);

} catch (Exception $e){
echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

However, I made another file in my customer folder named 'read_one.php' which also needs a GET request. Is it possible to have these 2 in the same folder? Sounds really newby, but I am

Comment: what is your criteria to use one file rather than the other in the folder? Does the router know it? If not, it's always possible to have a main PHP file in the folder that will include the first or second file depending on your criteria.

Comment: @Kaddath The criteria is what type of request someone sends the API. They go to /api/customers and if it's a GET, it returns /read, if it's a POST, it returns /create, etc.

Comment: I understood this, but your question is about using 2 different files to handle 2 different types of GET requests, right? so what's the criteria to differenciate them and to know which file to use?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. I think I'm just going to toss the file in a different folder.

Comment: as you like, but it's strange that you want to be able to handle 2 different GET requests without knowing what differentiates one from another.. :|